# How to find laurent series of $\exp(1/z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I want to find the laurent series of  $f(z)=\exp(1/z)$.

I started with the formula for laurent series: $f(z)=\sum_{0}^{\infty} a_n (z-z_0)^n +\sum_{1}^{\infty} b_n (z-z_0)^{-n}$, but I don't know how to apply it.

Can someone help me find the series?

Comment: Do you know the series expansion for $f(w)=e^w$? If you do, write that out and then see what happens when $w=1/z$.

Comment: @JamesCameron Yes that's it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Posting a comment as an answer)

Do you know the series expansion for $f(w)=e^w$? If you do, write that out and then see what happens when $w=1/z$.